# Getting "undefined" when trying to create new instance on Redux

Tags: javascript, react-native, class, redux, react-redux

I am trying to write the code to add a new product to my redux store after the new values are submitted from my form. But as a side effect, all my ids become 'undefined'
this is my redux code:

```
import PRODUCTS from "../../data/dummy-data ";
import Product from "../../models/product";
import {
  CREATE_PRODUCT,
  DELETE_PRODUCT,
  UPDATE_PRODUCT,
} from "../actions/productsActions";
const initialState = {
  availableProducts: PRODUCTS,
  userProducts: PRODUCTS.filter((prod) => prod.ownerId === "u1"),
};

function uid() {
  return (performance.now().toString(36) + Math.random().toString(36)).replace(
    /\./g,
    ""
  );
}
function productsReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case DELETE_PRODUCT:
      return {
        ...state,
        userProducts: state.userProducts.filter(
          (product) => product.id !== action.pid
        ),
        availableProducts: state.availableProducts.filter(
          (product) => product.id !== action.pid
        ),
      };
    case CREATE_PRODUCT:
      const { title, description, imageUrl, price } = action.payload;
      const newId = uid();
      const newProduct = new Product(
        newId,
        "u1",
        title,
        imageUrl,
        description,
        price
      );
      console.log({ newProduct });
      return {
        ...state,
        availableProducts: [...state.availableProducts, newProduct],
        userProducts: [...state.userProducts, newProduct],
      };

    case UPDATE_PRODUCT:
      const {
        id: prodId,
        title: updatedTitle,
        description: updatedDescription,
        imageUrl: updatedImageUrl,
      } = action.payload;
      console.log(action.payload);
      const productIndex = state.userProducts.findIndex(
        (prod) => prod.id === prodId
      );
      const productIndexInAvailable = state.availableProducts.findIndex(
        (prod) => prod.id === prodId
      );
      const updatedProduct = new Product(
        prodId,
        state.userProducts[productIndex]["ownerId"],
        updatedTitle,
        updatedImageUrl,
        updatedDescription,
        state.userProducts[productIndex]["price"]
      );
      const updatedUserProducts = [...state.userProducts];
      updatedUserProducts[productIndex] = updatedProduct;

      const updatedAvailableProducts = [...state.availableProducts];
      updatedAvailableProducts[productIndexInAvailable] = updatedProduct;

      return {
        ...state,
        availableProducts: updatedAvailableProducts,
        userProducts: updatedUserProducts,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default productsReducer;
```

the code not working:

```
function uid() {
  return (performance.now().toString(36) + Math.random().toString(36)).replace(
    /\./g,
    ""
  );
}
 case CREATE_PRODUCT:
      const { title, description, imageUrl, price } = action.payload;
      const newId = uid();
      const newProduct = new Product(
        newId,
        "u1",
        title,
        imageUrl,
        description,
        price
      );
      console.log({ newProduct });
      return {
        ...state,
        availableProducts: [...state.availableProducts, newProduct],
        userProducts: [...state.userProducts, newProduct],
      };
```

This is my product class:

```
class Product {
  constructor(id, ownerId, title, imageUrl, description, price) {
    this.id = id;
    this.ownerId = ownerId;
    this.title = title;
    this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    this.description = description;
    this.price = price;
  }
}

export default Product;
```

how I create my dummy-data:

```
import Product from "../models/product";

const PRODUCTS = [
  new Product(
    "p1",
    "u1",
    "Red Shirt",
    "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/10/02/22/17/red-t-shirt-1710578_1280.jpg",
    "A red t-shirt, perfect for days with non-red weather.",
    29.99
  ),
  new Product(
    "p2",
    "u1",
    "Blue Carpet",
    "https://images.pexels.com/photos/6292/blue-pattern-texture-macro.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260",
    "Fits your red shirt perfectly. To stand on. Not to wear it.",
    99.99
  ),
  new Product(
    "p3",
    "u2",
    "Coffee Mug",
    "https://images.pexels.com/photos/160834/coffee-cup-and-saucer-black-coffee-loose-coffee-beans-160834.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=bean-beans-black-coffee-160834.jpg&fm=jpg",
    "Can also be used for tea!",
    8.99
  ),
  new Product(
    "p4",
    "u3",
    "The Book - Limited Edition",
    "https://images.pexels.com/photos/46274/pexels-photo-46274.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=blur-blurred-book-pages-46274.jpg&fm=jpg",
    "What the content is? Why would that matter? It's a limited edition!",
    15.99
  ),
  new Product(
    "p5",
    "u3",
    "PowerBook",
    "https://get.pxhere.com/photo/laptop-computer-macbook-mac-screen-water-board-keyboard-technology-air-mouse-photo-airport-aircraft-tablet-aviation-office-black-monitor-keys-graphic-hardware-image-pc-exhibition-multimedia-calculator-vector-water-cooling-floppy-disk-phased-out-desktop-computer-netbook-personal-computer-computer-monitor-electronic-device-computer-hardware-display-device-448748.jpg",
    "Awesome hardware, crappy keyboard and a hefty price. Buy now before a new one is released!",
    2299.99
  ),
  new Product(
    "p6",
    "u1",
    "Pen & Paper",
    "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/10/03/02/14/pen-969298_1280.jpg",
    "Can be used for role-playing (not the kind of role-playing you're thinking about...).",
    5.49
  ),
];

export default PRODUCTS;
```

This is what I'm getting when I create a new product:
[redux logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B41xB.png)

I'm using react native and Redux.
Any help or insight would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an issue with uid() function rather than some redux side effect

Have you tried to log the result of uid(), or replacing performance.now() with something else like Date.now() or some unique id generators like
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-uuid